# Passing variable from view to element in cakephp

Tags: variables, view, cakephp-2.0, element

I have a view file add_rates.ctp and in that there is one select box . when i change the optiion, it will make a ajax call and fetch some values from the controller and load an element in that view.
but my problem is iam not getting the parameter values in the element.
i am getting params in rates.ctp

```
$params=$this->params['pass'];
```

it will return an array of parameters. but when i tried this in element i am not getting the value.
also i tried to set a value in the  add_rates.ctp and try to access in element, that is also not working

```
$this->set('params',array($params));
```

what to do..if anybody have idea about this please reply.. i get stucked ...

Answer (score 4):

If $params is the array you are trying to pass, then try this:

```
<?php $this->element('your-element-name', array('params' => $params)); ?>
```

Comment: i know this, but i want to get a value from my view itself